# Symfony2 + Assetic: Possible to dump compiled javascript into layout?

Tags: symfony, assetic

I'm developing a simple web site. I want to use coffeescript for my javascript, so I'm using Assetic to compile it.

How can I make assetic dump the compiled javascript into the web page itself instead of adding a link to the external file? This is for an mobile app so I want to keep network traffic to a minimum

Answer (score 0):

Inside `{% javascripts %}` you can use `asset_url` only. Extension will not set anything else.